# impresspages -- Is there a simple way to align images center, left, or right?

Tags: impresspages

I see it's easy to change the image size, make it link to something, or change the title and description, but what I don't see is an option to align the image right, left, or center.  Am I missing something?

I'm using the Air theme, if that matters.  I'm new to Impresspages.

Thanks!

Edit:
Just to make it absolutely clear what I'm asking:
I'm using Impresspages.  I want to insert an image and make it align to the right, for example.
I have no trouble dragging and dropping the image widget to where I want it to go.  I have no trouble uploading the image.  If I wanted to, it is quite clear how to change the image size, how to add a link, and how to change the title and description of the image.

However -- I would have thought there would have been an option to align the image to the left, right, or center, but there is no such option.  I have checked Stackoverflow very carefully, as well as the Impresspages site, and I don't see anywhere how to do what should be a really simple thing.

Am I missing something?  Or do I need to just learn how to do without right aligning my images?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by dragging image widget next to other widget on any side. It that case it will align where you want. Here's an example - http://cdn.impresspages.org/core/file/2014/04/03/Impresspages_no_colum_01_1_2.gif

To make it centered is a bit tricky. There are no straightforward way of doing it.

If you really really need this, you can try using RichText widget. It allows to insert image into a text as it is in any text documents.

Comment: OOOOOOOOOOOH Thank you so much!  I knew there must be an easy way to do it.  It seems so obvious now!! ;)  And thanks for the tip about centering.  I'll give that a try.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You can create additional skin for Image widget to be centered http://www.impresspages.org/docs/widgets#skin

Geeky way. But going to work.